# Dollar sign + double curly braces inside string in google sheets (some kind of variable?)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, double-click-advertising

I'm reviewing a google sheet that relates to an application I'm being asked to replicate, and there's something in one of the cells that I haven't encountered before and am not sure how to deal with it. It appears to me to be a variable of some sort (the syntax is similar, but not identical, to a handlebars expression), but I can't find where/how it's declared or where/how it's getting its value. Unfortunately, I have very little to present here code-wise, so I'm really just hoping someone has encountered this same thing and can shed a little light on what it is (I've changed the literal text to just be nonsense, but the main thing I'm trying to figure out is how the "${{price}}" aspect of this works).

Example:

```
'${{price}} discount from blah blah blah. Legal jargon, blah blah blah.'
```

I also have template JS that is related to this (though I don't know exactly how), but I'll paste the only reference I'm able to find to this variable within the code:

```
if (getManufacturerPriceSavings() === 0) {
   string = string.replace('${{price}} discount.', '');
}
```

Again, apologies for the apparent lack of code to look at with this one, but hopefully this is familiar enough to someone that it won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Im still a newbie to this, and I hope I havent misunderstood the question, but `{{price}}` looks to be a template variable, used in a templating language. The price value may be kept in a database out of the code, so that may be why you can't find it.

Comment: I think you're right in terms of this being a variable, I'm pretty certain of that. My bigger question is where the variable is declared and where/how it's pulling in its value. This may not be an issue for what I have to build, but if it doesn't work out of the box I'm concerned I won't be able to troubleshoot it efficiently.

Comment: Where the variable is declared would depend on your set up and code, It would be difficult to find from here but look for replaces in both the sheet and the JS code.

Comment: Agreed. The issue is it's inherited from another dev who I don't have access to so I'm left to kind of figure it out based on what I have access to (in other words, it's someone else's setup and code for the most part; if I set it up, I would hope I know what's happening with that variable haha). The js snippet I included above is the only location in the js where that's referenced at all. I think I'll just have to do a deep dive into any other sheets I can find to try and figure this out.